# Finding row with closest numerical proximity within Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame with the following hypothetical data:

```
   ID    Time        X-coord      Y-coord
0  1      5          68          5
1  2      8          72          78 
2  3      1          15          23 
3  4      4          81          59 
4  5      9          78          99 
5  6     12          55          12 
6  7      5          85          14 
7  8      7          58          17 
8  9     13          91          47 
9  10    10          29          87
```

For each row (or ID), I want to find the ID with the closest proximity in time and space (X & Y) within this dataframe. Bonus: Time should have priority over XY. 
Ideally, in the end I would like to have a new column called "Closest_ID" containing the most proximal ID within the dataframe.

I'm having trouble coming up with a function for this.

I would really appreciate any help or hint that points me in the right direction!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: how do you define `closest proximity` ?

Comment: I think the problem is not well-defined - let's say that ID2 is closest to ID1 in terms of time, but ID3 is closest in terms of space. Which one should be on the closest_ID column?

Comment: please supply an expected output

Comment: Time should have highest priority, and then "sort by" XY. I probably need to normalise the data first, so I can work with distances in percent...

Answer (score 1):

Let's denote `df` as our dataframe. Then you can do something like:

```
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances

space_vals = df[['X-coord', 'Y-coord']]
time_vals =df['Time']
space_distance = pairwise_distance(space_vals)
time_distance = pairwise_distance(time_vals)

space_distance[space_distance == 0] = 1e9 # arbitrary large number
time_distance[time_distance == 0] = 1e9 # again

closest_space_id = np.argmin(space_distance, axis=0)
closest_time_id = np.argmin(time_distance, axis=0)
```

Then, you can store the last 2 results in 2 columns, or somehow decide which one is closer.

Note: this code hasn't been checked, and it might have a few bugs...

Comment: It's not running as is, but it's pointing me in the right direction, thanks! Once I'll figure it out I'll give an update!